# Input textbox not responding to bootstrap column system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following snippet of code. I basically need to show a search icon attached to a search box, which next has a cancel button attached.

I took 2 columns for the icon and button and 8 columns for the search box.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="input-group col-lg-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon col-lg-2">
      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>            
    </span>

    <input class="form-control col-lg-8" type="text" placeholder="Search..."/>

    <span class="input-group-addon col-lg-2 btn btn-default">
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So I want everything to show in a single row with no margins but all I get is this. The input box takes all the width instead of 8 columns

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not try a different approach and just adjust the overall column width like so? http://jsfiddle.net/00g1atuq/1/

Comment: Worked like a charm, I had to add all the column definitions (lg, md, sm, xs) to make it work for every screen size.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can set ***.input-group-addon{min-width:200px}*** (what ever you wanted size) and for the responsiveness you can add several ***@media screen*** sizes

[**Live Demo jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/qjnk8zck/4/)

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .input-group-addon{
         min-width:200px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .input-group-addon{
         min-width:100px;
    }
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>  </span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
        </div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

:)

Comment: This solution is not very elegant